# Android create widget to start other apps but in the background

Tags: android, widget

I have an Android radio that doesn't autostart apps but it can start apps from widgets. I want to make a widget that will start various apps I choose but I want them to only open other apps then close them or open in the background so once all the apps are started, the home screen is still showing. I already have a simple AppWidgetProvider I'm using from another project:

```
public class AppStarterWidget  extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         final int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                            R.layout.widget_layout);

                    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.btnStartActivity, "setBackgroundResource",
                            R.drawable.circle_off);

                    try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
                        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.my.app", "Qualified name"));
                        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                context, 0, intent, 0);
                        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnStartActivity, pendingIntent);
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
                        //handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                "There was a problem loading the application: ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thought I would give a little work around for others that may want to start an app in the "background." I use quotes because it's not actually in the background but seems like it.

DISCLAIMERS: I created a routine to start the program and immediately afterword I relaunch the Home Screen. Since my point was to have a widget to run apps that would normally get a boot completed broadcast, there is the possibility this won't work if the same code is not called by the launcher activity.

You will also want to deal with the logic regarding how and when this is called because it goes to the Home Screen. So if whatever called it has an activity in the foreground it will be moved into the background.

Also, this is not complete code but should be enough to give you the idea. Requires a SharedPreference of the packagename as true to start the app. Otherwise it just iterates through and is done. I also included a little code to handle recalling without restarting the apps over and over if you wanted to put in a timer loop.

```
public class LaunchAppInBackground extends AppCompatActivity {

    static SharedPreferences sPrefs;
    static boolean bUpdatingAppSelection;
    private static ArrayList<String> alStartedApps = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        startAllApps(this);
    }

    static void startAllApps(Context context) {

        if(bUpdatingAppSelection) {
            return;
        }

        final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List<ResolveInfo> launchables = context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        // Loop through all apps
        for (ResolveInfo launchable : launchables) {

            // If app is in Preferences
            if (sPrefs.getBoolean(launchable.activityInfo.packageName, false)) {

                // Check if already launched
                Log.i("AI", "Checking " + launchable.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
                boolean bAlreadyLaunched = false;
                for (String s : alStartedApps) {
                    if (s.equals(launchable.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName)) {
                        bAlreadyLaunched = true;
                    }
                }

                // Start if not already launched
                if (!bAlreadyLaunched) {
                    alStartedApps.add(launchable.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName);
                    startApp(launchable, context);
                } else {
                    Log.i("AI", launchable.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName
                            + " already running");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void startApp(ResolveInfo launchable, Context context) {
        if(launchable != null) {
            ActivityInfo activity = launchable.activityInfo;
            ComponentName name = new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    activity.name);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.setComponent(name);
            context.startActivity(i);
            loadHomeScreen(context);
            Log.i("AI", "Launched " + activity.applicationInfo.packageName);
        }
    }

    static void loadHomeScreen(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```